# how to check whether specific word are included in dictionary value - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I want to make a search program but i stuck in specific alogrithm.
First, I will get any word from users
Then check wheter user's words are included in any keywords from di value. If user's words are included, then return key value as list type. If user's words are not included, then execute the program.

For example, if I input "nice guy", then function should return 'matthew' as list type.

```
dic_1 = {'matthew':'he is a nice guy', 'dennis':'he is a bad guy', 'alex':'he is a good guy'}
dic_2 = {'manchester': 'city from england', 'tokyo':'city from japan', 'rome':'city from italy'}

def searchWords(*dicts):
    list_check = []
    search = input("Enter word for search: ")
    for dic in dicts:
       if search in dic[word]:
          list_check.append(keyword)
       else:
          print("None")
          break
print(searchWords(dic_1))
```

I keep stuck in for approaching the algorithm...
I hope you guys give me any advice or idea to make this algorithm.

Comment: You need to loop through all key:value pairs in the dict and then check whether the word is included in the value or not

Comment: `print(x[0]) if len(x:=list(filter(lambda x: search_str in x[1], {'matthew':'he is a nice guy', 'dennis':'he is a bad guy', 'alex':'he is a good guy'}.items()))) else 'not found'
` with `filter`

Comment: Please add, what you found out while debugging the failing example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is

```py
dic_1 = {'matthew':'he is a nice guy', 'dennis':'he is a bad guy', 'alex':'he is a good guy'}
dic_2 = {'manchester': 'city from england', 'tokyo':'city from japan', 'rome':'city from italy'}

def searchWords(*dicts):
    lst = []
    t = input('Write something to search:')
    for dict_ in dicts:
        for k,v in dict_.items():
            if t in v:
                lst+=[k]
    return lst
```

Using list Comprehension.

```py
def searchWords(*dicts):
    t = input('Write something to search:')
    lst = [k for dict_ in dicts for k,v in dict_.items() if t in v]
    return lst
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like as below using list comprehension to pull out the matching keys:

```
dic_1 = {'matthew':'he is a nice guy', 'dennis':'he is a bad guy', 'alex':'he is a good guy'}
dic_2 = {'manchester': 'city from england', 'tokyo':'city from japan', 'rome':'city from italy'}

def searchWords(dictex):
    search = input("Enter word for search: ")
    return [k for k,v in dictex.items() if search in v]
print(searchWords(dic_1))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter word for search: nice guy
['matthew']
```

**Another Output :**

```
Enter word for search: guy
['matthew', 'dennis', 'alex']
```

Answer (score 0):

## comprehension

First, you can merge your dictionaries using **ChainMap**

```
from collections import ChainMap
chain = ChainMap(*dicts)
```

Then you can search using list comprehension for better performance

```
results = [v for v in chain.values() if 'keyword' in v]
```

## filter

You can also do it with the python **filter** function

```
newDict = dict(filter(lambda elem: 'keyword' in elem[1], chain.items()))
```